# disable right click on iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to disable right click on iframe but my code is not working. any fix for this code or any alternate to disable right click on iframe pdf?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Disable Context Menu</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/jscript">
         $('#myiframe').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
         return false;
         }); 
      </script>
   </head>
   <body >
      <iframe id="myiframe" src="dummy1.pdf" width="528" height="473"  
         ></iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Iframes have their own window and events occur in that window, not parent page. Events do not bubble up to the iframe element from the inner window. Since you are rendering a pdf in that window I highly doubt you will be able to do what you are asking in any way that will work cross browser

Comment: I have to wonder at the need for preventing right click of an `iframe`'d pdf. Preventing right-click via javascript doesn't actually prevent the user from doing whatever it is they wanted to do. It just annoys them and then they go and use some other means in the browser to accomplish their goal.

Answer (score -3):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#myiframe').on('contextmenu', function() {
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

Also, try using the latest version of jQuery. The latest version of jQuery is `3.5.1`.

Comment: exact copy from OP